# JS/CSS: Cannot restyle HTML elements, possibly due to JS animations still running?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I am trying to restyle (CSS) some HTML elements on my website, **after** certain animations (JS Web Animations API) have been applied to these elements and said animations have finished. However, for some reason, I am unable to restyle the elements.

What I think may be happening is that some animations are not finishing correctly, which, in turn, prevents me from restyling the objects which were being animated.

An animation looks like this:

```
for (letters of letter)
{
        let animation2 = letter.animate([
            {transform: `rotate(${letterCurrentRotation}deg)`},
            {transform: `rotate(${nearestAngle}deg)`}
            ],
            {
                fill: "forwards",
                duration: 1000,
                iterations: 1
            });
        
        animation2.addEventListener("finish", () => {
        animation2.commitStyles();
        console.log(`animation ${animCounter} finished. animation playstate: ${animation2.playState}. Letter ${letters[animCounter].innerHTML}`)
        animCounter++;
        if (animCounter >= letters.length)
        {
            animCounter = 0
        }
        animation2.cancel();
        })
}
```

This gives following console output:

```
 animation 0 finished. animation playstate: finished. Letter A
 animation 1 finished. animation playstate: idle. Letter R
 animation 2 finished. animation playstate: idle. Letter P
 animation 3 finished. animation playstate: idle. Letter H
```

Which is fine, since there are 4 letters being animated. This initially leads me to believe the animations have finished correctly. However, since I cannot restyle the animated elements, I check if there are any animations still active using `document.getAnimations()` which gives following output

```
(3) [Animation, Animation, Animation]
0: Animation {effect: KeyframeEffect, startTime: 1684.7069999203086, currentTime: 1000, playbackRate: 1, playState: 'finished', …}
1: Animation {effect: KeyframeEffect, startTime: 1684.7069999203086, currentTime: 1000, playbackRate: 1, playState: 'finished', …}
2: Animation {effect: KeyframeEffect, startTime: 1684.7069999203086, currentTime: 1000, playbackRate: 1, playState: 'finished', …}
length: 3
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

This, in turn, leads me to believe some animations **have not** finished.

- From my understanding, `document.getAnimations()` should not list
  animations that have had their `cancel()` method invoked? Is this
  understanding correct?
- Why would `document.getAnimations()` list animations, even though
  their `finish` event has cleary been fired?
- Why would animations still "stick around", **and thus prevent me from restyling elements**, even though finish has been fired?